# What is $\lim_{\sigma\to0}\int_{B(x^\star,r)}\mathcal{N}(x|x_0,\sigma^2I_d)dx$?

Tags: integration, limits

What is $\lim_{\sigma\to0}\int_{B(x^\star,r)}\mathcal{N}(x|x_0,\sigma^2I_d)dx$?

Here $B(x^\star,r)$ is an open ball centered at $x^\star$ with radius equals to $r$, $\mathcal{N}$ represents a Gaussian distribution and  $I_d$ is a $d$-dimensional identity matrix.

It is not difficult to prove that

1) If $||x^\star-x_0||_2<r$, the limitation is $1$. In this case, $x_0$ is inside the open ball $B(x^\star,r)$.

2) If $||x^\star-x_0||_2>r$, the limitation is $0$. In this case, $x_0$ is outside the open ball $B(x^\star,r)$.

What if $||x^\star-x_0||_2=r$? This means $x_0$ is on the boundary of the open ball. Intuitively speaking, the result should be $\frac{1}{2}$. But how can I prove it?

Comment: Change variables, writing $z=x/\sigma$.  The region of integration gets closer and closer to a half space, whose boundary contains  $x_0$, whose limiting gaussian measure converges to $1/2$.